# How can I match two lists of lists only if some values match?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have two lists of lists `A` and `B`. `A` has more than 15 sublists and does not have the same length has the other list. I would like lists in `A` to be merged with lists in `B` if there are matching values inside lists in `B`.

Here's a small example:

```
A = [[3,10],
     [4,25,31],
     [2,10]]

B = [[2,6,9,10],
     [15,25,26], 
     [2,6,8,10],
     [16,20,21]]
```

I would like my results to be like this:

```
C = [[[2,3,6,9,10,10] 
      [2,3,6,8,10,10]], 
     [[4,15,25,25,26,31]], 
     [[2,6,9,10,10], 
      [2,2,6,8,10,10]]]
```

Comment: please show your current code

Comment: `[sorted((A[i] if i < len(A) else []) + B[i]) for i in range(len(B))]` if you want to merge the two lists. Your expected value however doesn't make much sense, since I don't get where you derived the 3rd index from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compute the Cartesian product of those iterables and check the intersections of the lists:

```
C = []
for a in A:
    c = []
    for b in B:
        if len(set(a) & set(b)) > 0:
            c.append(sorted(a + b))
    if len(c) > 0:
        C.append(c)
```

If you want to have something more compact using list comprehensions (and you're using python >= 3.8):

```
C = [c for a in A if len(c := [sorted(a + b) for b in B
                               if len(set(a) & set(b))])]
```

Here is the output using your `A` and `B` lists:

```
[[[2, 3, 6, 9, 10, 10],
  [2, 3, 6, 8, 10, 10]],
 [[4, 15, 25, 25, 26, 31]],
 [[2, 2, 6, 9, 10, 10],
  [2, 2, 6, 8, 10, 10]]]
```